# Xamarin, assign image to ImageView in Fragment

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, imageview

How can I assign a drawable png to ImageView in Fragment?
I declare an ImageView in tab's layout:

> ImageView
>
> ```
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content "
>       android:layout_rowSpan="2"
>       android:id ="@+id/iv_icon"
> ```

The tab class is here:

> class tabFragment1 : V4Fragment
>
> {
>
> ```
>     public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saved)
>     {
>         var v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tabLayout1, container, false);
>         return v;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

I want to assign an .png from drawable folder , something like this:

> ImageView iv_icon = FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv_icon);
> iv_icon.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_weather_cloudy_white_48dp);

If I put it in the MainActivity OnCreate() method (below the ViewPager initialisation, of course), I get NullRefenceException Error (on the second row).
The question is: in which class should I put these statements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fragment `OnCreateView` once you had inflated the view/layout you can access its ui elements, in your case your ImageView.

Modify this method:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saved)
{
    var v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tabLayout1, container, false);

    ImageView iv_icon = v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv_icon); 

    iv_icon.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_weather_cloudy_white_48dp);

    return v;
}
```

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the instantiation of your ImageView. You can't just call FindViewById, you have to call FindViewById from your fragment reference. Such as:

```
ImageView iv_icon = fragmentName.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv_icon); 
//fragmentName is the reference to your fragment *after its been inflated*
```

The exception is being thrown because your trying to call SetImageResource from an ImageView that was instantiated improperly. The ImageView is null and hence a NullReferenceException is being thrown.

On a side note, inflation of a view from an Activity will work as follows:

```
View v = FindViewById(Resource.Id.X);
```

FindViewById is a convenience method so that you don't have to keep calling activityName.FindViewById(). **This convenience does not exist for fragments.**

In summary, inflating a view from an Activity:

```
View v = FindViewById(Resource.Id.X);
```

Inflating a view from a fragment:

```
View v = fragmentName.FindViewById(Resource.Id.X);
```